# simplexml_load_file() error

Tags: php, simplexml

so I'm trying implement a website which uses data stored in an xml file.
It works fine on my computer, but as soon as I try to upload it, I get the following error:

> Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: I/O warning : failed to load external entity "..\lib\menu.xml" in /home/ogwareco/public_html/menu.php on line 2

And none of the data gets displayed on the screen. I've Googled this problem, but it's led nowhere. I've got no idea what to do here. I've even tried to set my permissions to 777 (bad idea, I know), to see if it was a permissions thing, but it's not.

Comment: Can you show us the partial code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using backslashes to refer to the file on a Linux machine. Change

```
..\lib\menu.xml
```

to

```
../lib/menu.xml
```

in your code.